# Is there a good implementation of partial file downloading in PHP?

Tags: php, download, resume

I'm writing a PHP script that allows the user to download a file. Basically the idea is to prevent the file being downloaded more than X times, since it is paid content, and the link should not be spread around.

Since the files will be pretty large, it should be good to implement resuming. I've read [the standard](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt), but it's pretty long and allows for some flexibility. Since I need to get it done quickly, I'd prefer a stable, tested implementation of this feature.

Can anyone point me to such a a script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems that I found what I needed myself. So that other may benefit from this, here is the link: http://www.coneural.org/florian/papers/04_byteserving.php

And just in case the original page stops to work (the script is pretty old already), here is a copy of it:

```
<?php 
/*

The following byte serving code is (C) 2004 Razvan Florian. You may find the latest version at 
http://www.coneural.org/florian/papers/04_byteserving.php

*/
function set_range($range, $filesize, &$first, &$last){
  /*
  Sets the first and last bytes of a range, given a range expressed as a string 
  and the size of the file.

  If the end of the range is not specified, or the end of the range is greater 
  than the length of the file, $last is set as the end of the file.

  If the begining of the range is not specified, the meaning of the value after 
  the dash is "get the last n bytes of the file".

  If $first is greater than $last, the range is not satisfiable, and we should 
  return a response with a status of 416 (Requested range not satisfiable).

  Examples:
  $range='0-499', $filesize=1000 => $first=0, $last=499 .
  $range='500-', $filesize=1000 => $first=500, $last=999 .
  $range='500-1200', $filesize=1000 => $first=500, $last=999 .
  $range='-200', $filesize=1000 => $first=800, $last=999 .

  */
  $dash=strpos($range,'-');
  $first=trim(substr($range,0,$dash));
  $last=trim(substr($range,$dash+1));
  if ($first=='') {
    //suffix byte range: gets last n bytes
    $suffix=$last;
    $last=$filesize-1;
    $first=$filesize-$suffix;
    if($first<0) $first=0;
  } else {
    if ($last=='' || $last>$filesize-1) $last=$filesize-1;
  }
  if($first>$last){
    //unsatisfiable range
    header("Status: 416 Requested range not satisfiable");
    header("Content-Range: */$filesize");
    exit;
  }
}

function buffered_read($file, $bytes, $buffer_size=1024){
  /*
  Outputs up to $bytes from the file $file to standard output, $buffer_size bytes at a time.
  */
  $bytes_left=$bytes;
  while($bytes_left>0 && !feof($file)){
    if($bytes_left>$buffer_size)
      $bytes_to_read=$buffer_size;
    else
      $bytes_to_read=$bytes_left;
    $bytes_left-=$bytes_to_read;
    $contents=fread($file, $bytes_to_read);
    echo $contents;
    flush();
  }
}

function byteserve($filename){
  /*
  Byteserves the file $filename.  

  When there is a request for a single range, the content is transmitted 
  with a Content-Range header, and a Content-Length header showing the number 
  of bytes actually transferred.

  When there is a request for multiple ranges, these are transmitted as a 
  multipart message. The multipart media type used for this purpose is 
  "multipart/byteranges".
  */

  $filesize=filesize($filename);
  $file=fopen($filename,"rb");

  $ranges=NULL;
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) && $range=stristr(trim($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']),'bytes=')){
    $range=substr($range,6);
    $boundary='g45d64df96bmdf4sdgh45hf5';//set a random boundary
    $ranges=explode(',',$range);
  }

  if($ranges && count($ranges)){
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial content");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    if(count($ranges)>1){
      /*
      More than one range is requested. 
      */

      //compute content length
      $content_length=0;
      foreach ($ranges as $range){
        set_range($range, $filesize, $first, $last);
        $content_length+=strlen("\r\n--$boundary\r\n");
        $content_length+=strlen("Content-type: application/pdf\r\n");
        $content_length+=strlen("Content-range: bytes $first-$last/$filesize\r\n\r\n");
        $content_length+=$last-$first+1;          
      }
      $content_length+=strlen("\r\n--$boundary--\r\n");

      //output headers
      header("Content-Length: $content_length");
      //see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/misc/known_client_problems.html for an discussion of x-byteranges vs. byteranges
      header("Content-Type: multipart/x-byteranges; boundary=$boundary");

      //output the content
      foreach ($ranges as $range){
        set_range($range, $filesize, $first, $last);
        echo "\r\n--$boundary\r\n";
        echo "Content-type: application/pdf\r\n";
        echo "Content-range: bytes $first-$last/$filesize\r\n\r\n";
        fseek($file,$first);
        buffered_read ($file, $last-$first+1);          
      }
      echo "\r\n--$boundary--\r\n";
    } else {
      /*
      A single range is requested.
      */
      $range=$ranges[0];
      set_range($range, $filesize, $first, $last);  
      header("Content-Length: ".($last-$first+1) );
      header("Content-Range: bytes $first-$last/$filesize");
      header("Content-Type: application/pdf");  
      fseek($file,$first);
      buffered_read($file, $last-$first+1);
    }
  } else{
    //no byteserving
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Content-Length: $filesize");
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    readfile($filename);
  }
  fclose($file);
}

function serve($filename, $download=0){
  //Just serves the file without byteserving
  //if $download=true, then the save file dialog appears
  $filesize=filesize($filename);
  header("Content-Length: $filesize");
  header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
  $filename_parts=pathinfo($filename);
  if($download) header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename_parts['basename']);
  readfile($filename);
}

//unset magic quotes; otherwise, file contents will be modified
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

//do not send cache limiter header
ini_set('session.cache_limiter','none');


$filename='myfile.pdf'; //this is the PDF file that will be byteserved
byteserve($filename); //byteserve it!
?>
```

Comment: Vilx answer code works great for me. I need it for PDF's opening in browser window. and now it works.

Comment: It works well for local files but when use for download remote files, It can't generate resumable links.

Comment: @SiyamakShahpasand - What do you mean - "download remote files"? If the file that needs to be downloaded isn't on your server, then you're not downloading - you're redirecting.

Comment: @Vilix - I mean this script can't Download remote file straight to client with resume capability.

Comment: @SiyamakShahpasand - I'll repeat my question. What is a "remote file"?

Comment: @Vilix - files that aren't on my own server.

Comment: @SiyamakShahpasand - Well, that's a bit beyond the scope of this script. The simplest way would be to download the file from that remote server to your own server, and then just act as if it's a local file. The only other option is to make your script act as a proxy. PHP's CURL functions offer the `CURLOPT_RANGE` flag with which you can forward the requested byte range to the remote server. Of course, in that case the remote server needs to support partial downloads too.

Comment: @Vilix - Tanks for ur reply. Could u please give some sample code about how to this? also I ask [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15717709/909802) question but anyone didn't help me.

Comment: @SiyamakShahpasand - That would be pretty lengthy and I don't know all the necessary functions by heart. Just google for "PHP download file" and you should find something that allows you to download the remote server to your server.

Comment: @Vilx- I used this script but it won't generate resumeable links through `byteserve()` method!

Comment: @NullPointer - Unfortunately I never got to test it, so I can't really comment. :( Also, PHP's evolved since then. Maybe there's something incompatible with the latest versions in the script?

Comment: Downvoted it, not worked for me. My goal is to send an `MP4` video and play it in `HTML5` video player.

Comment: @H.Farid - I don't know much about video streaming, but I suspect that partial downloads there might be a bit more involved than just sending parts of the file. Try searching for information video in particular. Also, this script is over 10 years old now - PHP might have changed too.

Comment: Thanks, @Vilx. I'll check that.

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

An alternative is to let the web server can handle http by redirecting to the file in question.

A PHP script can do any checks needed (security, authentication, validate the file, incrementing the download count) and any other tasks before calling header("Location $urltofile");

I tested this with apache. Interrupt/resume download works. The server's mime type configuration will determine client behavior. For apache, if defaults in mime.types are not suitable, configuration directives for mod_mime could go in a .htaccess file in the directory of the file to download. If really necessary, these could even by written by the PHP script before it redirects.

Comment: The header('Location:') idea is a bad one, because the validation is trivial to bypass. Your link is also broken, but I managed to find the code you mentioned on the site. Too bad it's copyrighted to the teeth and I must contact the website to be allowed to use it. But it still seems valid.

Comment: @Vilx- It's okay if the file path has a long random string, which changes regularly and the old ones are removed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using PEAR HTTP_Download. It is pretty easy to use and it allows download resuming just file:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-download.intro.php

Answer (score 1):

Based on this:

http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/

(which you also could use)

I've made a small lib that does what PECL http_send_file extension does:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-send-file.php

(which you also could use)

The lib resembles the http_send_file, but if you don't have the option of installing the PECL lib, you could use the http-send-file lib:

https://github.com/diversen/http-send-file

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of implementing web server in a web server (yo dawg!) you could use [mod trigger before download](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModTriggerBeforeDownload) in lighttpd or [mod X-Sendfile](http://tn123.ath.cx/mod_xsendfile/) available for both lighttpd and Apache2?

Comment: A module like this would be more useful: if a URL is accessed which is flagged, then make an HTTP call to a specific hardcoded URL, forwarding all received headers. If the response is 200, then allow access, if not, then deny. (I was unable to find a module like that.)